# Python: Connect blender with WinTracker 2

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to develop a project that uses a **control model** in **Blender** by using **WinTracker machine**, but I don't know how to connect it with `Blender Game Engine`.

How can I connect it with `Blender Game Engine`?

Answer (score 0):

You must write the plug-in for blender and used the wintracker driver. It is ready for c Lagrange.
but you have "wintracker2"?

I wanted to buy it but the company said "it's not ready to seal".